# kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException (no error message) while building APK using Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, kotlin, apk

I am new to Jenkins and trying to generate APK.I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have added git credentials and gradle script is as below:
[image]

Note: I have a build Type named "Dev"

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of stack-traces. It's even truncated and therefore as good as no stack-trace at all. And without the code which produces the issue, that's just alike "it's not working". How shall one answer that? Are you sure to have  the Android SDK setup for the user which runs `jenkins`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes, I do have Android SDK setup for the user. Also, the build is successful when compiled from Android Studio.

Comment: When you go to that workspace directory, can you manually run `gradlew.bat assembleDebug`? In case this should succeed, you can be certain that there is something not setup properly for the `jenkins` user. It could also be, that a required file had not been checked into version control.

Comment: I took a fresh clone and ran `gradlew.bat assembleDebug`, it built successfully. So, the check-in is accurate

Comment: On Windows, there should be "run as different user" ...try this with the `cmd` box. When it builds with your current user, but not the jenkins user, then it's definitely the environment which is not setup properly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this problem while configuring my jenkins for an android project, and finally found the problem, after even formatting my pc.

The gradle just cannot find where the Android SDK is located.
Adding this to .zshrc (or .bashrc, whatever shell you are using) resolved my problem:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<your-user-here>/Library/Android/sdk`

Don't forget to verify if the specified folder above contains the folder sdk.

Edit: I did this in a macOS environment, you should look for the correct sdk location in your OS.

Comment: And don't forget set environment ANDORID_HOME in Jenkin

Comment: Or add local.properties file to your project. with content:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/<your-user-here>/Library/Android/sdk
```

Replace the dir above to match your system

Answer (score 0):

you're missing local.properties file in root project.

it should have ndk, sdk paths

```
ndk.dir=/home/sudendra/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669
sdk.dir=/home/sudendra/Android/Sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Some how the path of your SDK has been changed in local.properties.

It should be same as :

File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK | Android SDK path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am building Android APK and I enabled `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true` based on suggestions in output logs while compiling.
I started facing this error after enabling it.

After removing `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true` from `gradle.properties`, it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

my case, I solved by upgrading Gradle JDK 17 2023

[image]